# Publishing snupkg symbols to specific folder in Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I'm trying to `nuget push X.Y.Z.nupkg -Source  https://local-artifactory.com/.../repo-name/X.Y.Z`.

Local folder contains `X.Y.Z.snupkg` file as well which is **not** being published , probably because of https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/11871

The only way I can get the `snupkg` published is to have

`nuget push X.Y.Z.snupkg  -Source Artifactory` where `Artifactory` is defined in `nuget.config` file with source `https://local-artifactory.com/.../repo-name` (without `X.Y.Z` folder path suffix), it's being published to the **root** folder.

Is there any way to have `snupkg`  published to `X.Y.Z` folder ?